# Strange numpy array assignment after copy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

I stumbled today upon this issue and I cannot see what's the problem:

```
print(np.unique(label))
>>> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]

LAC = label
print(np.unique(LAC))
>>> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]

print(np.unique(label))
>>> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]

LAC[LAC != 4] = 0
LAC[LAC == 4] = 1

print(np.unique(LAC))
>>> [0. 1.]

print(np.unique(label))
>>> [0. 1.]
```

Is it somethings I do wrong ? `label` is a numpy array `(44,640,640)` and `LAC` is just supposed to be the copy of `label` but for some reason it gets affected too ?

I don't understand where this comes from. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAC = label` does **NOT** copy `label` into a new array. It is simply assigning the same object to `LAC`. Thus, when you change one, the other also changes. Think of it as both being the same array with different names.

If you wish to make a new copy of your array, use `np.copy`. Here is an example to make it clear:

```
label = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])
print(np.unique(label))
#[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]

#LAC and label point to the same object
LAC = label
#this changes both LAC and label
LAC[LAC != 4] = 0

print(np.unique(LAC))
#[0. 4.]

print(np.unique(label))
#[0. 4.]


label = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])
#make a new copy of label
LAC = label.copy()
#this changes ONLY LAC
LAC[LAC != 4] = 0

print(np.unique(LAC))
#[0. 4.]

print(np.unique(label))
#[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know that. Is it the same with all variables or this concerns just numpy array ? I just tried and you are completely right ! I should be more careful. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ehsan **NO** it does **not** depend on the type of object, **assignment never copies**. Not `float` or `int` or *anything*. All objects have the exact same semantics as far as assignment goes in Python.

Comment: @Unic0 just to be clear, assignment *never* copies, regardless of the type. You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: A float doesn't make a copy, but it isn't mutable.  So this kind of a problem doesn't arise.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing out the language. I tried to explain the same thing with wrong words. The correct term is rebinding and mutating. Floats are rebinded and arrays are mutable (assuming you don't define a type and twist python assignment)

Comment: @Ehsan I'm not sure what you are saying, but again, just to be clear, assignment always rebinds regardless of the type. Immutable types simply lack mutator methods, but the semantics of assignment is always the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just as counter-example for overloading assignment for methods: https://gist.github.com/jamalex/5997735 Nonetheless, the simple assignments do not copy as you said.

Comment: @Ehsan That is specifically *attribute assignment*, where yes, the behavior can be controlled by the type. But you can never change the way `name = whatever` works.